# Moving Dynamics CRM 2011 tracked email attachments into SharePoint 2010 document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, attachment, documents, dynamics-crm-online

In order to concentrate all CRM entity related documents in SharePoint, and minimize the growth of the CRM database footprint we have decided to store CRM tracked email attachments in SharePoint, but there currently is no out-of-the-box mechanism to do so.  To work around this, we are manually populating the SharePoint document library with the email attachments and appropriately updating metadata (related entity name, user, date, tags, etc.).  To see the documents and attachments from within CRM, we have created an IFrame on the associated CRM entity forms that links back to a custom SharePoint view into the document library.  This view is filtered on the entity name via URL parameters.  This is working much better for us than the out of the box document management in SharePoint which is not flexible enough in how it stores documents, primarily because it uses folders and can't easily update metadata.  However, the documents still remain as tracked email attachments within CRM (and Exchange mailboxes, but we don't really care about this).  What we would like to do, is copy/or move the attachments into SharePoint, updating the metadata as appropriate, and then replace the attachment in CRM with the URL of the new SharePoint document.

With that as the background, we would appreciate some guidance from more experienced CRM and SharePoint experts in this forum.  Our questions are these:

-Which makes more sense as a mechanism for getting the attachments from an email into SharePoint:  an Outlook plugin with an action that can be triggered manually by the user, or a workflow that is triggered when the set-regarding action is used within CRM or Outlook?  Is there another solution that we are missing?  **We do always use the Set-regarding action on an email to point to the entity that the attachments should be associated.**

-We also have a need for bulk document uploader that associates the documents to an entity via an added field in the document library in Sharepoint containing the entity’s name.   Currently we use SharePoint’s bulk document loader, and then manually update the metadata as best we can using a data grid view.   It seems like leveraging the code needed for handling the email attachments could be readily used here, but again I am not sure what vehicle to use:  an Outlook plugin, CRM workflow/dialog process, SharePoint plugin or stand alone app.

-Finally, at this time the relation between an CRM entity and its associated documents in the SharePoint document library is completely dependent upon the entity name.  This is not robust, because the CRM entity name could change at any given time, and then the associated metadata would need to be updated.  The correct solution is for the relationship to be based upon the CRM entity ID field instead.  What is the best way to get access to CRM entity data from within SharePoint? Note that we are currently using Office 365 for email and SharePoint, and Dynamics CRM 2011 Online, so direct access to the databases is not available.

Any guidance that you provide would be greatly appreciated!